# How to enter two digits from same textfield in AWT/SWING

Tags: java, swing

I have created a Simple calculator in which I take inputs of two operands in two different textfields, and it is working good. But I need to take two inputs from same textfield. What changes should I make?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Calculation_ActionEvent extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JFrame f;
    JLabel l;
    JTextField tf1, tf2, tf3;
    JButton b1, b2, b3, b4 ,b5, b6;
    Calculation_ActionEvent(String s)
    {
        f = new JFrame("Calculation");
        f.setLayout(null);
        l = new JLabel("Enter two numbers : ");
        tf1 = new JTextField();
        tf2 = new JTextField();
        tf3 = new JTextField();
        b1 = new JButton("+");
        b2 = new JButton("-");
        b3 = new JButton("*");
        b4 = new JButton("/");
        b5 = new JButton("equals");
        b6 = new JButton("C");
        f.add(l);
        f.add(tf1);
        f.add(tf2);
        f.add(tf3);
        f.add(b1);
        f.add(b2);
        f.add(b3);
        f.add(b4);
        f.add(b5);
        f.add(b6);
        tf1.setBounds(180,100,50,30);
        tf2.setBounds(320,100,50,30);
        tf3.setBounds(250,420,50,30);
        b1.setBounds(250,180,50,30);
        b2.setBounds(350,260,50,30);
        b3.setBounds(150,260,50,30);
        b4.setBounds(250,340,50,30);
        b5.setBounds(230,260,90,30);
        b6.setBounds(250,100,50,30);
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        b3.addActionListener(this);
        b4.addActionListener(this);
      //b5.addActionListener(this);
        b6.addActionListener(this);
        f.setSize(550,550);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        int num1= Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
        int num2= Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText());
        String s1 = e.getActionCommand();
        if(s1.equals("C"))
        {
            tf1.setText("0");
            tf2.setText("0");
            tf3.setText("0");
        }
        else
        {
         if(s1=="+")
        {
            tf3.setText(String.valueOf(num1+num2)); 
        }
        if(s1=="-")
        {
            tf3.setText(String.valueOf(num1-num2)); 
        }
        if(s1=="*")
        {
            tf3.setText(String.valueOf(num1*num2)); 
        }
        if(s1=="/")
        {
            tf3.setText(String.valueOf(num1/num2)); 
        }
        }
 }

    public static void main(String... s)
    {
        new Calculation_ActionEvent("Calculation");
    }
 }
```

Comment: Actually this is my first program in Swing..please help me get through it.

Comment: Do you mean something like "4+4","8" (ie the two inputs in one text field), instead of "4","4","8"? You should include an example, it would help.

Comment: i mean to hav one textfield in which firstly i will write one operand , then press the operator , and then the second operand in the same textfield itself, while storing the first value in some variable..and then printing the result in second text field. Example: in typed 5 in textfield, pressed '+' and typed 3 in the same textfield.. to get the answer 8 in second textfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this be something like what you're looking for? I did a quick version for you.

Simply put, I store the last operator (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`) in a `String` variable (`lastAction`), the `total` as an `int`. When "equals" is pressed, I work out the total and reset the `total` variable and `lastAction`. When an operator is pressed, I change the total but keep the last value in a variable.

```
package cf.pgmann.calc;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class Calculation_ActionEvent extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JFrame f;
    JLabel l;
    JTextField tf1, tf3;
    JButton b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6;

    Calculation_ActionEvent(String s) {
        f = new JFrame(s);
        f.setLayout(null);
        l = new JLabel("Enter two numbers : ");
        tf1 = new JTextField();
        // tf2 = new JTextField();
        tf3 = new JTextField();
        b1 = new JButton("+");
        b2 = new JButton("-");
        b3 = new JButton("*");
        b4 = new JButton("/");
        b5 = new JButton("equals");
        b6 = new JButton("C");
        f.add(l);
        f.add(tf1);
        f.add(tf3);
        f.add(b1);
        f.add(b2);
        f.add(b3);
        f.add(b4);
        f.add(b5);
        f.add(b6);
        tf1.setBounds(160, 100, 250, 30);
        // tf2.setBounds(320,100,50,30);
        tf3.setBounds(250, 420, 50, 30);
        b1.setBounds(250, 180, 50, 30);
        b2.setBounds(350, 260, 50, 30);
        b3.setBounds(150, 260, 50, 30);
        b4.setBounds(250, 340, 50, 30);
        b5.setBounds(230, 260, 90, 30);
        b6.setBounds(420, 100, 50, 30);
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        b3.addActionListener(this);
        b4.addActionListener(this);
        b5.addActionListener(this);
        b6.addActionListener(this);
        f.setSize(550, 550);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    int total = 0;
    String lastAction = "";

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int num = 0;
        try {
            num = Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
        } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {}
        String s1 = e.getActionCommand();
        if (s1.equals("C")) {
            tf1.setText("");
            tf3.setText("0");
            tf1.requestFocus();
            total = 0;
        } else if (s1.equals("equals")) {
            tf3.setText(String.valueOf(calc(total, lastAction, num)));
            tf1.setText("");
            tf1.requestFocus();
            total = 0;
        } else {
            total = total==0 ? num : calc(total, lastAction, num);
            tf3.setText(String.valueOf(total));
            tf1.setText("");
            tf1.requestFocus();
            lastAction = s1;
        }
    }

    private int calc(int num1, String action, int num2) {
        switch (action) {
        case "+":
            return num1 + num2;
        case "-":
            return num1 - num2;
        case "*":
            return num1 * num2;
        case "/":
            return num1 / num2;
        default:
            return num1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... s) {
        new Calculation_ActionEvent("Calculator");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the value from the two textbox and perform all the calculation addition,multiplication,subtraction,divide and store in different variable and the set that variable in textbox you cant directly perform the action in textbox.ex below

```
String val1=textbox1.gettext();
String val2=textbox2.gettext();
int addition=Integer.ParseInt(val1)+Integer.ParseInt(val2);
textbox3.settext(addition.toString());
```